# Поток "умирает" в SurfaceView

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-handler

Пишу игру на SurfaceView и интересует такой вопрос. В потоке игры мне нужно поменять булевую переменную и я решил использовать Handler.postDelay все бы хорошо, но почему то в консольке пишет что поток уже "умер" привожу пример кода:

```
                if(!animate){
                animate = true;
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        animate = false;
                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                }
                },500);
                Looper.loop();
            }
```

В консоле пишет:

```
W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {df6a879} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {df6a879} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

Это все я делаю в потоке сюрфейса.

Comment: У вас через 500 мс поток умирает Looper.myLooper().quit();

Comment: Разве метод Looper.quit() не просто закрывает MessageQueue?

Comment: Вроде нет, полностью его останавливает

Comment: Тогда как блокировать поток до обработки сообщения?

Comment: Sleep. А для чего блокировка?

Comment: Ну, что бы он успел достать и обработать Message с очереди сообщений

Comment: Поток работает постоянно. А вот уже в нем можно сделать перехватчик